# To upgrade Here map SDK version (android)

Tags: android, heremaps

Im not strong developer in android development.

So.. Old application uses HERE SDK for Android (Starter Edition) 3.12
But it doesnt work with android 10+ (because of scoped storage)

How to upgrade version to 3.13 ?

Comment: P.S. Too many classes use SDK in old legacy project. so i dont want to adjust a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

The *Starter Edition* is no longer maintained. Using this legacy edition is not future proof. In the long run, consider to move to the *HERE SDK for Android (Explore Edition)*. Even if your project contains a lot of code, this not so difficult to do as it sounds. Here is a link to a [migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/dev_guide/topics/migration.html) that may be of some help.

Scroll to the end of this guide and look for the example app tables, they contain links to old code versus new code.